# addError on a form according to field values

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to add a custom field validation to my fields but I can't make it work...
Here is my code :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
            ->add('somefields', ChoiceType::Class, array(
                '...'
            ))
            ->add('tel', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => "Téléphone :",
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('cell', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => "Port. :",
                'required' => false
            ))
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (empty($data['tel']) && empty($data['cell'])) {
            $form->get('tel')->addError(new FormError('error message'));
        }
    });
}
```

What I want : 
if both fields are empty, warn that at least one field must be filled...
I'm trying different things for days, but I can't find any solution. I guess the answer is easy though...

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to do it in another way.
I've added a callback in my entity

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload) {
    if (empty($this->getTel()) && empty($this->getCell())) {
        $context->buildViolation('validation message')
                ->atPath('tel')
                ->addViolation();
        $context->buildViolation('validation message')
                ->atPath('cell')
                ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
if ( ($form->get('tel')->getData() == '') && ($form->get('cell')->getData() == '') ) {
     $form->get('tel')->addError(new FormError('error message'));
}
```

See if that works, not certain that it will or not.

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer but there's no difference, the form is still valid.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem; you have both 'tel' and 'cell' set to `'required' => false`. I wonder if you can change your design to add a "Telephone" and then set the "Type" to either "home/business/cell" and then make it required. That might be a better solution. This is just a suggestion though.